# .I want to do a pairwise.t.test of every column against every column in a dataframe

Tags: r, t-test, pairwise

[violin plots generated from data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM5xR.png)
The numbers in each column represent localisation of signal relative to another signal inside nuclei of cells. There are 3 treatment conditions and 7 time points of treatment + 2 controls giving a total of 23 columns (see violin plots). 
I would like to perform a t-test or a Wilcox t-test with each column to each column. I think I have done it before with a `pairwise.t.test(Chr)`. However, the function requires to define how you group your data and I would like to group mine by columns.
I've imported my data:

```
Chr <- read_csv("Chromocenters-intensity.csv", 
+     na = "NA")
```

> Parsed with column specification: cols(   .default = col_double() )

[Imported dataset into R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ1GY.png)

And then tried:

```
 pairwise.t.test(Chr, cols())
```

> Error in order(y) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(Chr,g=cols(Chr))
```

> Error: Some `col_types` are not S3 collector objects: 1

I do not understand what the errors mean.

a normal t.test works fine:

```
t.test(Chr$S0,Chr$S1)
```

> Welch Two Sample t-test
>
> data:  Chr$S0 and Chr$S1 t = 0.85955, df = 154.12, p-value = 0.3914
>   alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 95
>   percent confidence interval:  -1.920629  4.879370 sample estimates:
>   mean of x mean of y 
>   100.41579  98.93642

but how do I scale it up to include every column by every column?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use `expand.grid` and `apply`.

```
data <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:23,function(x){runif(470,1,200)}))
names(data) <-c(paste0("S",0:7),paste0("N",1:7),paste0("P",1:7),"TKO")
pairs <- expand.grid(names(data),names(data))
result <- data.frame(pairs,p.val = apply(pairs,1,function(x){t.test(data[x[1]],data[x[2]])$p.val}))
result
    Var1 Var2          p.val
1     S0   S0 1.000000000000
2     S1   S0 0.573722556263
3     S2   S0 0.874552764274
4     S3   S0 0.467670724537
5     S4   S0 0.700539636188
6     S5   S0 0.736422364244
7     S6   S0 0.599066387580
8     S7   S0 0.940641228509
9     N1   S0 0.727290760056
10    N2   S0 0.057120608982
11    N3   S0 0.523554180769
12    N4   S0 0.485633891380
```

Don't forget to correct later for multiple testing.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for you quick response. I tried it like that but the p-values don't make sense now. 
In my original test of S0 to S1 t.test the value is 0.3914 and now in the column the value is 0.5737
I also believe that at least some of the distributions from the columns are significantly different, especially between the controls, which is not what i'm seeing in the p.val column

Comment: Hi SisiDI, it's hard to know unless you provide the entire content of `Chromocenters-intensity.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi welcome to Stack Overflow!

First, make sure you do some p-value correction for the multiple tests you are running, `?p.adjust` might be helpful.

Second your problem requires you to get all of the possible pairing from your data set columns, which is a job for `?combn` to do:

```
mtcars_numbers <- dplyr::select_if(mtcars, is.numeric) # simulate some data like you describe

?combn
all_pairs <- combn(names(mtcars_numbers), 2, simplify = F)
all_pairs # I wanted a this to be a list for lapply, but you can get a matrix with simplify=T
```

Then you iterate over each pair, I'm using `?lapply()` but you could use a `for` loop or another function:

```
lapply(all_pairs,
       function(x) {
         t.test(mtcars[[x[1]]], mtcars[[x[2]]])
       })
```